# Add 'More options' on Navbar on window resizing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to show 'More options' collapsed button when window resizing to collapse every hidden `<li>`  like this example :

```
<li id="menu_more_container" class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More options<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul id="menu_more" class="dropdown-menu">
</ul></li>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: Need to be a lot more specific. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can manage all this with responsive utilities: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Just add `.visible-xs-*`etc where needed...

Comment: Yes thank you it is useful for desplay or hide button but the big probleme is to add hidden Ii in navbar to collapsed button  !!

Comment: There is problably a better and less heavy solution, but you can always create two completely different navbars and then use the responive utilities to show one or the other...

Comment: Thank you but i want the solution to collapse LI one by one that is what i need :(